# Non CRUD actions with ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Say I have the following ember-data model:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:  DS.attr('string'),
    starred:   DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

This communicates with a Rails app with the following pretty standard CRUD API:

```
GET    /people    - get a list of people
POST   /people    - create a new person
GET    /people/id - get a specific person
PUT    /people/id - update a specific person
DELETE /people/id - delete a specific person
```

This all maps to Ember-Data with the standard Store/Adapter.

However, lets say that in order to "star" or "unstar" a person, the API doesn't let us do this by the standard update action. There's a specific API endpoint for this action:

```
POST   /people/id/star   - mark a person as "starred"
POST   /people/id/unstar - mark a person as "unstarred"
```

How do I fit this API in with Ember Data?

It looks like I'd need to extend DS.Store and DS.RESTAdapter somehow, but I'm not sure of the best approach to make them aware of these different actions. It also feels a bit wrong that a generic Adapter for the app has to be aware of starring people.

Note that I have no control over the API, so I can't make `POST /people/id` aware of "starring" so that it would fit in with a standard update.

Comment: Could you accept my answer?  The currently accepted one is no longer accurate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the discussion group, Yehuda mentioned this isn't possible yet.

Comment: Cheers, I thought that might be the case as nothing jumped out in the source/tests.

Comment: This is now possible - see my answer below

Answer (score 10):

Been a while and it may not have been possible at the time, but you can call the ajax method of your adapter directly:

```
YourApp.Store.prototype.adapter.ajax(url, action, {data: hashOfParams})
```

For example:

```
YourApp.Store.prototype.adapter.ajax('/products', 'GET', {data: {ids: [1,2,3]}})
```

For your question:

```
YourApp.Store.prototype.adapter.ajax('/people' + id + '/star','POST')
```

*Edit* -  using buildURL is useful, particularly if you've set a namespace on your adapter:

```
url = YourApp.Store.prototype.adapter.buildURL('people',id) + '/star'
```

*Edit 2* - You can also get the adapter with `container.lookup('adapter:application')`, which is useful if you don't have global access to the app (ex ES6 modules / ember-cli)

*Edit 3* - The above refers to an outdated version of Ember / Ember-CLI.  Now I define this function in a mixin -

```
  customAjax: (method, type, id, action, hash = null) ->
    #note that you can now also get the adapter from the store -
    #adapter = @store.adapterFor('application')
    adapter = @container.lookup('adapter:application')
    url = adapter.buildURL(type, id) + '/' + action
    hash['data'] = $.extend({}, hash) if hash #because rails
    adapter.ajax(url, method, hash).then (result) =>
      return result
```

And call it like so -

```
@customAjax('PUT', 'modelClass', modelId, 'nonCRUDActionName', optionalHashOfAdditionalData).then (response) =>
  #do something with response
```

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same issue, and solved it using a modified version of what is explained in here: 
[Non-crud rails actions in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541820/non-crud-rails-actions-in-ember-js)

Basically, you need to use a Jquery AJAX call, the important part for me was to change the contentType in order to get the auth data to be sent in the request headers, rather than in form-data (the default, if you include data in your call). Also, make sure to give the proper context in the AJAX part, otherwise 'this' won't work in the 'success' callback:

```
App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    actions:
        starItem: ->
            controller = this
            item = @get 'model'
            id = item.id
            token = @auth.get 'authToken'
            $.ajax
                type: 'PUT'
                context: controller
                data: '{ "auth_token": "' + token + '"}'
                url: '/api/v1/items/' + id + '/star'
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                dataType: 'json'
                success: ->
                    if @get 'item.starred_by_user'
                        @set 'model.starred_by_user', false
                        item.decrementProperty('total_stars') 
                    else 
                        @set 'model.starred_by_user', true
                        item.incrementProperty('total_stars')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good start: https://github.com/beautifulnode/ember.request

Did not tryed it yet, but seems promising in your case...

Comment: Thanks, there are a few options for persistence but I'm currently giving ember-data a shot as I expect that'll be the default in the future.

Comment: @rlivsey did you eventually find a work around to use non-crud actions with ember-data and doing mind post back your solution here. Thanks

Comment: @mike I looked at the source code for minutefavors which has a non-crud action and route favors#tag and in your  **[Apps.TagView](https://github.com/mikecrittenden/minutefavors/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/app/views/favors/tag.js)**  you defined a url function that returns  '/favor/tags'. I know you used ember-resource for that app, how can we do something similar with ember-data restAdapter. Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not the same Mike as the one from minutefavors :-)

Comment: @brg I'm using my own custom persistence code at the moment so am not using ember-data for now

Answer (score 0):

I think, that in [CQRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation#Command_Query_Responsibility_Segregation) therms star and unstar are commands. So you should declare model PersonStar and work with it.